# Getting an error Notice: Undefined index: ref

Tags: php

First of all I am a new student of learning php. Currently I am writing a piece of code, But getting this error when i compile it.

```
Notice: Undefined index: ref in D:\xampp\htdocs\uploadthis\includes\config.inc.php on line 8
```

my file **config.inc.php**

```
<?php
require_once ('database/database.inc.php');
$myDb = new Db;
include ('siteconfig.inc.php');
require_once ('controls.inc.php');
if(isset($_COOKIE["usReferrer"])){
}else{
setcookie("usReferrer",limpiar($_GET["ref"]),time()+7776000);
}
?>
```

I hope you Guys can tell me how can i get off from this error.

Comment: what? Please write in details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not sending the parameter **`ref`** on your URL.

Make sure your URL looks like this ,

```
http://www.yourpage.com/somepage.php?ref=test
                           ---------^
```

Always use an **`isset`** construct to check whether the variable exists.

```
if(isset($_GET['ref']))
{
echo "Set";
}
else
{
echo "Not Set';
}
```

**EDIT :**

> I have used cookies. So in fine what my codes will be look like?

This is how you should do.

```
<?php
require_once ('database/database.inc.php');
$myDb = new Db;
include ('siteconfig.inc.php');
require_once ('controls.inc.php');

if(isset($_GET['ref']))
{
if(isset($_COOKIE["usReferrer"])){
}else{
setcookie("usReferrer",limpiar($_GET["ref"]),time()+7776000);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I have used cookies. So in fine what my codes will be look like?

Comment: Please rate my question. thanks